# NWJS updating progress bar during long loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having some troubles with javascript.
I'm trying to do a desktop app with NW.JS. I have a .xml file which I drag and drop in my app then it run a function to read the XML do some stuff and save a new file in .csv 
It's work fine but now i would be able to update a progress bar during the function...

I tried `setInterval` and `setTimeOut()` but I'mhaving always the same result : nothing append until the function is finished.

here is my code

```
  //Same as $(document).ready();
  function ready(fn) {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
    }
  }

  //When the page has loaded, run this code
  ready(function(){
    // prevent default behavior from changing page on dropped file
    window.ondragover = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false };
    // NOTE: ondrop events WILL NOT WORK if you do not "preventDefault" in the ondragover event!!
    window.ondrop = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false };

    var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
    holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
    holder.ondragleave = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
    holder.ondrop = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
########I'm doing stuff here to convert file and i want to update the progressbar##########

};
        reader.readAsText(file);
        //reader.readAsDataURL(file);

        return false;
    };
});
```

Thanks for your help

best regards,

Comment: `I'm doing stuff here to convert file and i want to update the progressbar` 1. there is no progressbar in the code you posted to update, 2. there is no code to update the non-existent progressbar in the code you've posted. ... are you asking how to implement a progressbar?

Comment: The progress bar is in html code. I know how to update progress bar with `document.getElementById("progressbar").style = ...`
The problem is that when I do it in my code inside a loop, progressbar didn't update dynamically but just update at the end of the code (100%).

Comment: Identical issue here: I see console.log in real time, but no DOM updates until the loop is finished. Am now looking at built-in `win.setProgressBar(progress)` but still need to update the DOM in real time.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the same code in NWJS and Electron, I found the problem to be that any long-running process in the 'main' Chromium process blocks rendering. The solution is to spawn a child process that communicates via Node's IPC. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56182694/418150).