# NWJS, Electron - DOM not updating during long-running process

Tags: electron, nwjs

Just as in [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124846/nwjs-updating-progress-bar-during-long-loop-javascript), I have a long-running process, during which I wish to update an the HTML of the app's only window -- but the DOM does not get updated until after the above process has completed.

This is the case with both NW and Electron.

The code *is* getting called, because the same routine also logs to the `console` - which is access through a `window` instance passed to the process, which is in a Node module.

I can find no documentation that references such issues, and no Chromium flag which might help.

When using `setInterval` to populate the `innerText` of an element with the time every second, the updates stop during the long-running file-parsing process.

Edit: this question is my first result on a Google search for 'NWJS not updating DOM'....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long-running processes that block the Chromium main process will also block the renderer.

The solution is to create a separate process, and have it send status updates back to renderer via IPC:

```
        this._service = fork(
            path.join(__dirname, 'service'),
            [],
            { stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit', 'ipc'] }
        );

        this._service.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('child error', err);
        });

        this._service.on('message', msg => {
            console.log('message from child:', msg);
            switch (msg.cmd) {
                case 'hello':
                    console.log('hello from parent');
                    break;
                case 'log':
                    this.parentLog(msg.html);
                    break;
                case 'progress':
                    this.progressBar.update(msg.pc);
                    break;
            }
        });
```

In the spawned subprocess (named `service.js` in the above example), use `process.send` to transmit JSON to the parent:

```
const childLog = (html) => {
    process.send({ cmd: 'log', html: html });
}
```

Note that if your parent is not the Electron renderer, it could be accessing the DOM via a `window` passed from the renderer.